# Flask route using path with leading slash

Tags: python, flask, routes

I am trying to get Flask using a simple route with a path converter:

```
@api.route('/records/<hostname>/<metric>/<path:context>')
```

It works unless the "path" part of the URL uses a leading slash. In this case I get a 404. I understand the error but what I don't get is that there is no workaround in the documentation or anywhere on the Internet about how to fix this. I feel like I am the first one trying to do this basic thing.

Is there a way to get this working with meaningful URL? For example this kind of request:

```
http://localhost:5000/api/records/localhost/disks.free//dev/disk0s2
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [`PathConverter` URL converter](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/routing/#werkzeug.routing.PathConverter) explicitly doesn't include the leading slash; this is deliberate because most paths should *not* include such a slash.

See the [`PathConverter` source code](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/5eed9385b861a1ae53c03eaae5a8dea4480113d6/werkzeug/routing.py#L893-L903):

> ```
> regex = '[^/].*?'
> ```

This expression matches anything, *provided it doesn't start with `/`*.

You can't encode the path; attempting to make the slashes in the path that are not URL delimiters but part of the value by URL-encoding them to `%2F`  doesn't fly most, if not all servers decode the URL path before passing it on to the WSGI server.

You'll have to use a different converter:

```
import werkzeug
from werkzeug.routing import PathConverter
from packaging import version

# whether or not merge_slashes is available and true
MERGES_SLASHES = version.parse(werkzeug.__version__) >= version.parse("1.0.0")

class EverythingConverter(PathConverter):
    regex = '.*?'

app.url_map.converters['everything'] = EverythingConverter

config = {"merge_slashes": False} if MERGES_SLASHES else {}
@api.route('/records/<hostname>/<metric>/<everything:context>', **config)
```

Note the `merge_slashes` option; if you have Werkzeug 1.0.0 or newer installed and leave this at the default, then multiple consecutive `/` characters are collapsed into one.

Registering a converters must be done on the Flask `app` object, and cannot be done on a blueprint.

Comment: It appears that even URL encoded, path doesn't like leading slashes. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24519076/python-flask-url-encoded-leading-slashes-causing-404-or-405

Comment: @DougT.: indeed, it looks like the slashes are decoded before url matching takes place. This *may* be server dependent too, but to have the built-in werkzeug server do this is pretty damnable for the idea. I'll remove the option from this answer.

Comment: I can't make this work (Flask 1.1.1, Werkzeug 1.0.0, Python 3.8.2).
No matter which converter I use, Flask only routes and reports the incoming URL with double slashes already collapsed into single slashes (no matter the position in the URL). The only exception seems to be `request.environ['REQUEST_URI']`, which, for now, I have to inspect directly.

Comment: @MortenB: right, reproduced and answer updated with a fix for that.