# Python Flask -- URL Encoded Leading Slashes causing 404 or 405

Tags: python, flask

My application frequently takes URL encoded strings as a URL parameter. Often these strings look like paths with a leading slash. IE `/file/foo`. In flask, I have an endpoint that takes a path parameter that I send a URL encoded path to. So I have something that looks like:

```
import flask
app = flask.Flask("Hello World")

@app.route("/blah/<path:argument>", methods=["GET"])
def foo(argument):
    return "GOT: %s" % argument

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This works great if I visit this URL:

```
http://localhost:5000/blah/cats%2F

returns:

GOT: cats/
```

But a leading slash with %2F fails with 404 in the case of GET and 405 in the case of POST. In other words, this 404s:

```
http://localhost:5000/blah/%2Fcats
```

In my research on this problem, I was lead to believe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24000729/flask-route-using-path-with-leading-slash) that URL encoding was sufficient to sole the problem. However that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: I'm afraid I was incorrect in my suggestion to use URL encoding. Mea Culpa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of how Werkzeug parses urls.  It decodes the encoded slashes before parsing the route, so they still appear as leading slashes.  There are bug reports about this:

- https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/issues/900
- https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/pull/478

The second link provides a patch to perform this decoding after routing, but it is not merged.

It looks like the best solution at this point is to follow [Martijn's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24000729/flask-route-using-path-with-leading-slash#24001029).

Answer (score 3):

One way to get around this without defining your own PathConverter is having two route filters:

```
import flask
app = flask.Flask("Hello World")

@app.route("/blah/<path:argument>", methods=["GET"])
@app.route("/blah//<path:argument>", methods=["GET"])
def foo(argument):
    return "GOT: %s" % argument

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Hitting this with:

```
http://localhost:5000/blah/%2Fcats
```

Gives me:

```
GOT: cats
```

And with:

```
http://localhost:5000/blah//cats
```

Gives me:

```
GOT: cats
```

But a better (cleaner) solution is probably the one described in this SO answer: [Flask route using path with leading slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24000729/flask-route-using-path-with-leading-slash#24001029)

Answer (score 0):

Use **path** type at the route.

> [path: Like string but accepts slashes.](https://exploreflask.com/en/latest/views.html#url-converters)

Eg: `@app.route('/test1/test2/<path:name>"')`

So **name** will be able to come with slash.