# How to url encode backslash in Flask restful?

Tags: python, rest, flask

My code is the following:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

resource_fields = {
    'messages': fields.String,
    'jsons': fields.String,
}

class DialogAPI(Resource):
    def get(self, sentence):

        dialog_result = generate_chat_json_str(sentence)
        logger.info(dialog_result)

        response = make_response(str(dialog_result))
        response.mimetype = 'application/json'
        return response

api.add_resource(DialogAPI, '/<string:sentence>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False, use_reloader=False, host='0.0.0.0', port=3000)
```

Then in Browser, I query like this:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/sentence=hello%2Fworld
```

The 'hello%2Fworld' is the encoded version of 'hello/world'. My query parameter could contain backslash.

However, it always gives this error message:

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

Comment: There is already an answer that could help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24001029/6361329

Comment: My problem is not the leading slash, but a slash in the middle. Is that the same?

Comment: I don't think the position matters because a web server recognizes it as a path delimiter and tries to find a route that can handle the request.

Here is another answer that explains this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24533109/6361329

Comment: Hi, @adkl, could you give an answer in reference to my code above? I am new to restful and haven't been able to get it working.